# cURL returns 200, browser timeout. AKS, LB, nginx

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I try to set up simple nginx deployment on AKS. The problem is I can't open the site on browser because of timeout. Curl works perfectly. I can't figure how browser connection may vary from cURL. Into browser address bar and cURL I put nginx-service external IP:

```
➜  kgs -n nginx
NAME            TYPE           CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP    PORT(S)        AGE
nginx-service   LoadBalancer   10.0.24.78   xx.yy.zz.30   80:31755/TCP   61s
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: nginx
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  namespace: nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.23.1
        ports:
        - name: web-port
          containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
  namespace: nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: nginx
  ports:
  - name: web-port
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: web-port
```

```
➜ curl -I xx.yy.zz.30
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Comment: When in the browser are you going directly to IP `xx.yy.zz.30` or are you in a `localhost` environment or entering a domain  ...

Comment: Directly to IP xx.yy.zz.30.